# Why doesn't the mute command not work in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

The `.mute` command doesn't work for some reason. Can someone help me out?

**My code:**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def mute(ctx, arg):
    user = client.get_user(int(arg))
    role = get(user.server.roles, name="Muted")
    async with ctx.typing():
        time.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send('Muted: ', '<@', int(arg), '>')
    client.add_roles(user, role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `mute` command with this:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def mute(ctx, id: int):
    member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(id)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'Muted')
    async with ctx.typing():
        time.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f'Muted: {member.mention}')
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

**Note:** I recommend replacing `time.sleep(1)` with `await asyncio.sleep(1)`. In this case you'll have to import `asyncio`.